# error message when using wget to Internet : Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... failed: Connection refused

Tags: internet, connection, localhost

when running:

```
wget https://gitlab.com/marsat/CTparental/uploads/35fd33508a49915869fa43820a7d2c36/ctparental_debian9_lighttpd_4.44.05-1.0_all.deb
```

Here is the result:

```
converted 'https://gitlab.com/marsat/CTparental/uploads/35fd33508a49915869fa43820a7d2c36/ctparental_debian9_lighttpd_4.44.05-1.0_all.deb' (ANSI_X3.4-1968) -> 'https://gitlab.com/marsat/CTparental/uploads/35fd33508a49915869fa43820a7d2c36/ctparental_debian9_lighttpd_4.44.05-1.0_all.deb' (UTF-8)
--2020-01-05 12:12:22--  https://gitlab.com/marsat/CTparental/uploads/35fd33508a49915869fa43820a7d2c36/ctparental_debian9_lighttpd_4.44.05-1.0_all.deb
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
```

There are several questions here related to server use, but I have not found one for client use. The wanted file exists on gitlab.com and I can download it via the browser without any problem.

I have no iptables rule preventing anything:

```
iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Here is my network configuration:

```
ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  
          inet adr:192.168.0.xxx  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Masque:255.255.255.0
          adr inet6: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Lien
          adr inet6: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Global
          adr inet6: xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:419919 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:238886 errors:19 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1000 
          RX bytes:519444509 (495.3 MiB)  TX bytes:27771976 (26.4 MiB)
          Interruption:17 

lo        Link encap:Boucle locale  
          inet adr:127.0.0.1  Masque:255.0.0.0
          adr inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Hôte
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1333 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 lg file transmission:1 
          RX bytes:150478 (146.9 KiB)  TX bytes:150478 (146.9 KiB)
```

If I look at what servers are available locally for testing:

```
netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:54729           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5355            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:42711           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6011          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6463          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:36479           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:2049            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::49801                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5355                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::45331                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6011                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::56891                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::2049                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::33665                :::*                    LISTEN
```

Then try (not sure this is a relevant test):

```
wget localhost:6010
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|127.0.0.1|:8080... failed: Connection refused.
```

Any idea please?

Comment: What OS/release are you running?   The only OS mentioned is debian.  https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Are you using a system-wide proxy or something similar?

Comment: Non system wide proxy. I am under Debian Stretch 9.11, kernel 4.9.0-11-amd64

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The output of the `wget` command suggests that you are using a *proxy*.

Run the following command on the *same* terminal that you are running the `wget` command:

```
$ env | grep -i proxy
```

Then run `unset` command for every variable listed from the above output. For example:

```
$ unset http_proxy
```

Check once more that the variable is removed (using again `env | grep -i proxy`).

Re-try the `wget` command.

The above is only a temporary solution. To permanently remove the proxy definition, go to system settings (`gnome-control-center`), navigate to **Network**  and **Network Proxy** and disable it.

Comment: env | grep -i proxy
http_proxy=localhost:8080
https_proxy=localhost:8080
no_proxy=localhost;
That works now, thanks !